# Error: no coincide un token en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Por favor ayúdenme, se lo agradecería de antemano, desde el dia de ayer me presenta aquel problema en phpmyadmin he estado buscando informacion pero no he encontrado hasta el momento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, este tipo de preguntas no se ajusta a las normas de la plataforma, porque se trata de una librería externa y no hay un código con el que podamos ayudarte. Suele ser más rápido encontrar la solución preguntando a san google, donde encontré [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358867/phpmyadmin-error-mismatch-token) (en inglés) y creo que puede servirte.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez tube el mismo problema que tu @ISAAC lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

```
$token_mismatch = true;
```

a

```
$token_mismatch = false;
```

en \xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php